# How to make an inner class without putting the definition of inner class to parent class?

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I'll write an header file,and it's very long.Since it will be too complicated,i don't want to put inner class definition in root class.I mean how can i make a class inner without writing it in root class.

```
class outer
{

}

class inner
{

}
```

If i can use like that, The header file will be clearer i think.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

```
// foo.hpp

class Foo
{
public:
  class Inner;
  Foo();
  void bar();
  Inner zoo();
};
```

```
// foo_inner.hpp

#include "foo.hpp"

class Foo::Inner
{
  void func();
};
```

Then, in the implementation:

```
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "foo_inner.hpp"

void Foo::bar() { /* ... */ }
void Foo::Inner::func() { /* ... */ }
```

Note that you *can* use the incomplete type `Foo::Inner` inside the class definition of `Foo` (i.e. in `foo.hpp`) subject to the usual restrictions for incomplete types, e.g. `Inner` may appear as a function return type, function argument, reference, or pointer. As long as the member function implementations for the class `Foo` can see the class definition of `Foo::Inner` (by including `foo_inner.hpp`), all is well.

Comment: One note: if the users of `Foo` need to interact with `FooInner` then they obviously also need the inner class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify 'outer' as "public class outer", and put both its definition and the "inner" definition into a "class.java" file, and code in outer can instantiate inner just as if inner was in a different source file.  It is not clear that is what you're after, because you have not explained why you want an "inner" class.

Comment: OP removed the ambigous Java tag, the question is no about C++ only.