# Friendship in nested classes C++

Tags: c++, friend

I am trying to understand concept of friendship in nested classes but I am not getting the concept properly. I have written a sample program to understand it but the program is not working

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class outerClass
{
    private:
        int a;
    public:
        class innerClass;
        bool print(innerClass);
};

class innerClass
{
    friend class outerClass;
    private:
        int b;

    public:
        innerClass() =default;

};

bool outerClass::print(outerClass::innerClass obj)
{
    cout<<"Value of b in inner class is:"<<obj.b;
}

int main()
{
    outerClass in;
    outerClass::innerClass obj;
    obj.b=5;
    in.print(obj);
}
```

I am getting below errors:

```
try.cpp: In member function ‘bool outerClass::print(outerClass::innerClass)’:
try.cpp:26:6: error: ‘obj’ has incomplete type
try.cpp:11:15: error: forward declaration of ‘class outerClass::innerClass’
try.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
try.cpp:34:28: error: aggregate ‘outerClass::innerClass obj’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
```

As I read through articles on internet I learnt following points please comment on them if they are correct or not:

- innerClass can access all the members of outerClass by default.
- For outerClass to access private members of innnerClass we need to make outerClass as friend class to innerClass.

Please help in pointing out the mistake in code and also if the points I understood are correct.

Comment: Here's [a hint on definition of inner classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693590/how-to-make-an-inner-class-without-putting-the-definition-of-inner-class-to-pare) outside the outer class definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to define `innerClass` outside of `outerClass`, here is how to do it:

```
class outerClass
{
    class innerClass; // forward declaration
};

class outerClass::innerClass // definition
{
};
```

The rest is OK, except of `obj.b=5`. The class `outerClass` is allowed to access `innerClass::b`, the function `main()` is not.

---

> innerClass can access all the members of outerClass by default.

Right. From the standard **[class.access.nest]**:

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.

---

> For outerClass to access private members of innnerClass we need to make outerClass as friend class to innerClass.

Right. From the standard **[class.access.nest]**:

> The members of an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class;

Comment: I corrected that mistake but still I am not able to access private member of innerClass in print function. Can you please help?

Comment: @MayankJain please see the Demo.

Comment: Do you mean ? "you can't do it in main"..(you wrote can)

Comment: @MayankJain Right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

The line `class innerClass;` within `outerClass` is a *forward declaration* to a `class` that you never define.

Hence `outerClass::innerClass` is an *incomplete type*.

The separate `innerClass` definition that starts with

```
class innerClass
{
```

is a *completely* different `class` to the forward declared class.

There's nothing wrong with your `friend class outerClass;` statement within the defined `innerClass`.

Comment: Sorry that was a trivial mistake. I correct it but even now I am not able to access private member `b` of innerClass in print function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing with `nested class` and `friend class`
You can use `friend class` not using `nested class` and
you can use `nested class` not using `friend class`

Here are some example:

```
class A {};
class B {};
```

Here the A class knows the B class, but the B cannot know the A class. So you need to tell the A class that the B class is exist.
This doing thing, is called **Forward Declaration**
So:

```
class B;       // forward declaration
class A {};    // A knows the B
class B {};    // B knows the A
```